# Dependencies are placed under web-inf/lib properly, but cannot access the api's of dependencies when deployed the .war file on tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependencies, war

I have few spring boot projects, the structure is as follows:

```
parent: war

    ---child1: jar

    ---child2: jar

    ---child3: jar

    ---child4: jar
```

child1,child2,child3,child4 are dependencies of parent.

when I build the parent project as a war, child projects are added as dependencies in web-inf/lib. But when I run the .war file(parent), the child projects are not triggered.

And, when I run the parent project in an IDE, it works fine...(I can access the child projects).

Is there any way to trigger the child projects and access the api's of child projects when we run the war file of parent.

**Note:
Here the issue is not placing the dependency jars in web-inf/lib folder, but to access the those jars during runtime.**

Comment: The parent can not be a `war` (packaging:war) if you tried so you should got a failure in Maven... do you use multi module setup ? The war has to be a different module which will create the final war... (if you really need to create a war)

Comment: Yeah, I use a multi-module setup. Under that comes all the projects including parent.

Comment: Look inside the generated war to see if things are as you expect.

Comment: I have all the dependency jars present in web-inf/lib folder. But when I deploy the war file on any external server, the api's in those jars are not coming up.